# What is the proper way to animate clutter actors that have been added in a LayoutManager?

Tags: animation, gnome, vala, clutter

I have a stage that contains a number of [Clutter.Actor](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-1.0/Clutter.Actor) (and one [GtkClutter.Actor](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-gtk-1.0/GtkClutter.Actor) embedding a `TreeView`) that were added to a layout manager (let's say the `GridLayout`).

And now I want to move them around with animations, using `translation_x`, `translation_y` and resizing their `width`.

**What is the recommended way to do that?**

Won't the layout that places actors according to rules conflict with the new positions of the actors?

Should I sever the ties to the layout (by nullify the `layoutmanager` property) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All `ClutterLayoutManager` implementations respect the easing state of an actor, so if you set the duration of the easing state to a non-zero value, all changes in allocation will be implicitly animated. You can see the effect in the [layout manager example](https://git.gnome.org/browse/clutter/tree/examples/layout-manager.c) shipped with Clutter itself.

An easing state with a non-zero duration will also allow you to transition things like `width` and `height` properties, as well as the transformation properties, such as `translation-x` and `translation-y`.

It is important to note, though, that transformation properties do *not* affect layout management; if you change the scale, depth, rotation, or translation of an actor, you do so after the actor has been given an allocation. You can use this knowledge to implement transitions.